# How to move Joomla accounts to my Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, joomla1.5

I have a 1.5 Joomla website that I am planning to re-write as a Ruby On Rails website. 
There are about 300 registered users, Is there an easy way to migrate my users accounts to devise gem based accounts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do some similar migration this way:

1. Create devise model users with additional fields for old password hash and salt
2. Copy all users from old database into new (new password hash will be empty, because we don't know actual user's pass)
3. Patch auth method - when user try to sign in with account without new pass hash (it means that this is old user) - we authenticate him by old auth algorithm, and if it passes, we create for his password new pass hash (using devise)

Comment: oh, it seems a little bit detailed process, can you please point me to any reference or blog that talks about a similar case ? or may be an example, thanks very much

Comment: Its ok, can you please explain the third point, "we authenticate him by old auth algorithm", how can I authenticate the user with the old auth algorithm of Joomla ? just little Pseudocode example of code to illustrate  idea ..

Comment: You need to investigate joomla source code for this :) And represent it in your ruby code

Comment: ouch! ;-p ok, thanks, I wonder if you can generously put your Ruby code within the answer ? it will be a great time saving, here is a vote up too! :-)

Comment: Ok, I can show you my code https://gist.github.com/ea0ce77e6455455f67d0 - but I migrate not from joomla, it was self made auth plugin for rails 2.3

Comment: Thanks very much Mik, I found it simple, I just need to encrypt the entered password with MD5, and then, do User.where(:old_password=> MD5(password), :username=> username) .. 
I found some thing interesting helped me here: http://lab11.com/blogs/Write-an-Advanced-Joomla-1.5-Authentication-Plugin.html
happy coding!

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old, but came across this and then later found the answer, so I'll post for others.

The password field in joomla is the md5 of the password and the randomly generated salt plus  a colon and the randomly generated salt.

It'll look something like this:

```
33da105d239879dae4cdaf58557985c:L8QwPXN02cltv0lkGIyD3JRDU0AR5fcA
```

So to get back to it...

1) Query the db for the username (posted by user)

```
user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
```

2) Then split the password and get 2nd element in array:

```
salt = user.password.split(":")[1]
```

3) Take the password (posted by user), plus the salt and check it against the one in the db

```
user.password == Digest::MD5.hexdigest(params[:password] + salt).to_s + ":" + salt
```

If you have the right user/pass combo, it should be true...

Comment: Thanks Jess, I didn't know that salt is combined within the password field in Joomla